# CP violation and matter- anti-matter asymmetry

Tags: cp-violation

It is clear that C violation is a must for matter-antimatter asymmetry. But why CP violation also necessary for the same?

Comment: Related questions/answers: [Why both C and CP violation is necessary for baryogenesis?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304038), and [Importance of CP violation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234319), and [What distinguishes the behaviour of particle from its antiparticle: C violation or CP violation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/410881), and [Sakharov condition of departure from equilibrium](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146362)